# How to disable the 'Set Windows password' on Google VM Instances?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I was wondering if there is a way to disable the "Set Windows password" option that shows up in a user's VM Instance in the Google Cloud VM Instances dashboard?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to disable the functionality although users will continue seeing the button. It is possible to remove permission from the user account in order to prevent that your users be able to use it, may you want to check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/creating-passwords-for-windows-instances#command-prompt) where explains the needed permissions to set a windows password, as per my understanding removing the role compute.instances.admin should be enough to prevent using the button.

The permissions that is necessary to remove is including by default in roles like owner, then it is necessary remove owner roles from the account that you want to restrict and assign a role which allow them work into your project, that's why I believe this [document](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) can help you to clarify some doubts about how permissions and roles work on GCP.